# Sonarqube with Cxx plugin does not show bugs only code smells

Tags: sonarqube

We have SonarQube 6.0 with  Cxx (Community) 0.9.7-SNAPSHOT installed.

Although we receive code smell issues the number of reported bugs is 0.

Does anyone have a clue why that might be?

Best regards
Marc

Comment: We have implemented an issue on purpose - nevertheless Cxx only reports code smells and no bugs.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out by talking to the developers of the Cxx-plugin it needs another plugin like cppcheck to have the bugs generated.